# Ignore floating-point overflow and underflow errors in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, floating-point

The following code snippet

```
void main()
{
   float a = 68440675640679078541805800652800.0f;
   float b = a*a;
   cout << b << endl;
}
```

produces a floating-point overflow runtime error in MSVC 2017. I do not want to check if the float a is small enough for a muliplication.

How is it possible to tell the C++ compiler to build a programm which ignores floating-point overflow and underflow errors? Researching for an answer I came across the function _controlfp_s at

https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/controlfp-s?view=vs-2019

But I did not manage to get it to work.

Comment: Warning C4756 is a compile time error and is letting you know that at __compile time__ `float b = a*a;` will produce overflow.  What value do you want to be stored into `b` (at compile time) in this case?

Comment: The above code snippet compiles just fine. The problem is that I am getting a runtime error. And I am asking how to set up the compiler so that the program will ignore the runtime error. The value to be stored in b is not relevant for me.

Comment: Warnings are not "compile time errors" @Richard. They can be made to act as errors but they are not errors.

Comment: Show us this runtime error, @BlueTune.

Comment: The runtime error shown in the output reads:
Exception thrown at 0x000000014012D7EC in Main.exe: 0xC0000091: Floating-point overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000000011A8).
Unhandled exception at 0x000000014012D7EC in Main.exe: 0xC0000091: Floating-point overflow (parameters: 0x0000000000000000, 0x00000000000011A8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Microsoft Visual C++ you can use _controlfp_s to get and to set the floating-point control word. For your code snippet a possible solution would look like:

```
int main()
{
    unsigned int fp_control;
    //Reading
    _controlfp_s(&fp_control, 0, 0);
    //Make changes
    unsigned int new_fp_control = fp_control | _EM_OVERFLOW | _EM_UNDERFLOW;
    //Update
    _controlfp_s(&fp_control, new_fp_control, _MCW_EM);

    float a = 68440675640679078541805800652800.0f;
    float b = a*a;
    out << b << ed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the specific `MSVC` warning using the following `#pragma` (but it *must* be outside and before the `main` function):

```cpp
#pragma warning(disable:4756)
void main()
{
   float a = 68440675640679078541805800652800.0f;
   float b = a*a;
   cout << b << endl;
}
```

The compiler will then *silently* give `b` the specific IEEE code that marks a floating-point value as "infinity" ([see this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Positive_and_negative_infinity)) and your `cout` line will reflect that.

At any point, you can re-enable the warning using a similar `#pragma` line but replacing "disable" with "default".